# Adding a HandlerInterceptor using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter instead of WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have the following configuration for my app:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityApiConfiguration
  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  ...
}
```

And I wanted to add an `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`. Is that possible using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`? I just see examples using `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.

Comment: Why not using `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`? Defining one configuration class per each architectural aspect of your app is better than having one *God Configuration* class, like your `SecurityApiConfiguration` which is a configuration class for security, data access and MVC, I'm afraid.

Comment: And if it's a Spring Boot application, that `@EnableTransactionManagement` will be provided by the right starter packages and seems redundant to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So is it correct to have to configurations for just one Spring Boot application? I mean, having one extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and another extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.

Comment: Yeap it's perfectly fine and even reasonable to do so. If you have a big configuration file, it's better to break it into smaller but more cohesive configurations

Comment: Just don't forget to annotate them with `@Configuration` and Also, if you're using Spring Boot read more about their starter packages and auto configurations provided by them http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-starter

Answer (score 0):

I was also faced same issue with Spring-boot 2.0, Since the reason behind why it doesn't support as name itself says `HandleInterceptor`, always associated with `WebMVCConfigurationAdpater`. And in other hand as we have extent support filter with `WebSecurityConfigureAdapter` we make an use of `OncePerRequestFilter`

```
public class SampleInterceptorFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //Your custom logic
       }

   }


    @Bean
    public SampleInterceptorFilter sampleInterceptorFilter() {
        return new SampleInterceptorFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    protected FilterRegistrationBean sampleInterceptorFilterRegistor() {
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        bean.setFilter(sampleInterceptorFilter()());
        bean.setName("SOME_NAME_FILTER");
        bean.setEnabled(false);
        return bean;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        //Here we need to configure accordingly order of filter plays vital role
        http.addFilterAfter(cyzfilter(), ExceptionTranslationFilter.class).addFilterAfter(xyzFilter(),
                ServiceUserPreAuthFilter.class).addFilterBefore(SampleInterceptorFilter(), ServiceUserPreAuthFilter.class);

    }
```